# How to download file from cloudflare using curl?

Tags: shell, curl, cloudflare

As part of pipeline for building Debian package with popular game Factorio i need to download game's distribution files. This is without any problems in gui web browser.

I try to download file using curl but i still cannot solve problem with CSRF token:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

LOGIN=""
PASSWD=""
VERSION=`curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/wube/factorio-data/tags" | jq -r '.[0].name'`
ARCHIVE="factorio_alpha_x64_${VERSION}.tar.xz"


CSRF=`curl -s -c ~/cookie.txt https://www.factorio.com/login | grep csrf_token | awk -F'"' '{print $8}'`
curl -v -c ~/cookie.txt -b ~/cookie.txt  -H "X-CSRF-Token: ${CSRF}"  -X POST -F "csrf_token=${CSRF}" -F "username_or_email=${LOGIN}" -F "password=${PASSWD}" https://www.factorio.com/login
curl -c ~/cookie.txt https://www.factorio.com/get-download/${VERSION}/alpha/linux64 > ${ARCHIVE}
```

The script run fail everytime with the final response:

```
vitex@exiv:~/Projects/Packaging/Games/factorio-deb$ ./downloader.sh 
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 104.26.14.88:443...
* Connected to www.factorio.com (104.26.14.88) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=sni.cloudflaressl.com
*  start date: Jul  6 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Jul  5 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.factorio.com" matched cert's "*.factorio.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55eea0a17d10)
> POST /login HTTP/2
> Host: www.factorio.com
> user-agent: curl/7.76.1
> accept: */*
> cookie: session=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiMTk2MmVlODBkMDJiMGFhODQ0N2U1OGZiYTEyZGQzMThjZTY5MTFkZCJ9.YXicKQ.D93FhsjkngmtONrHEFB6P0d4w8Y
> x-csrf-token: IjE5NjJlZTgwZDAyYjBhYTg0NDdlNThmYmExMmRkMzE4Y2U2OTExZGQi.YXicKQ.HKcRPgEkSRVU4_Xat-dCV31sHWg
> content-length: 461
> content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------c63b0f58b7ac0deb
> 
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 256)!
< HTTP/2 400 
< date: Wed, 27 Oct 2021 00:24:09 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< cache-control: no-cache
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
< vary: Cookie
* Replaced cookie session="eyJfZnJlc2giOmZhbHNlLCJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiMTk2MmVlODBkMDJiMGFhODQ0N2U1OGZiYTEyZGQzMThjZTY5MTFkZCJ9.YXicKQ.PbtfNJW_assTK0ZkBWujMpBVnuM" for domain factorio.com, path /, expire 0
< set-cookie: session=eyJfZnJlc2giOmZhbHNlLCJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiMTk2MmVlODBkMDJiMGFhODQ0N2U1OGZiYTEyZGQzMThjZTY5MTFkZCJ9.YXicKQ.PbtfNJW_assTK0ZkBWujMpBVnuM; Domain=.factorio.com; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/
< via: 1.1 vegur
< cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
< expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=HZPVm%2FRu31d1J8IkHuFfcRwFad6vXWf2%2FbHrH3PCRg1GFuXfHgsJDXN10zPpE6ZaOP7I1ClCiaDo0i0tO%2B5kih95W6gO28pCyjiiA3oXOmJvFHr%2F4iipMg0xlK7v2rVQ51w%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< server: cloudflare
< cf-ray: 6a47c7a32c4f27a0-PRG
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title> 400 - CSRF Error | Factorio</title>

...
```

How i can better work with cookies recieved by first request ?

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Not a solution to the cookie issue, but if you could make due with the headless version of Factorio, it isn't behind a login (public link) and would bypass the CSRF issue completely. Not sure if this would help for your use case though, just thought I'd mention it!

Comment: @David this script is part of repackaging into DEB: https://github.com/Vitexus/factorio-deb/